# Create endpoint from query by method name, that is pageable/sortable

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I'm very new to spring boot, and I have a simple CRUD service that has a `RestRepositoryResource`:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CatalogueOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<CatalogueOrder, Long>,
    QuerydslPredicateExecutor<CatalogueOrder> {
}
```

I'm trying to create a custom endpoint, that can perform a pageable/sortable query for order statuses NOT equal to the provided query parameter. I attempted the following:

```java
@GetMapping("/test")
Page<CatalogueOrder> findByOrderStatusNot(String orderStatus, Pageable page);
```

When I attempt to hit the endpoint `/test`, I get a 404 error.

Am I exposing the endpoint wrong? And if so, have I defined the method correctly for what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to set the annotation `@RestController` in your controller.

Do it and try call again `http://localhost:8080/test`,

Source: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: Yes, that was it. While I don't have a standalone controller, it worked by adding the @RestController annotation to the Repository